Request works fine in browser but EXCACT request fails in Postman
I am requesting the API endpoint https://www.paknsave.co.nz/CommonApi/Account/GetCurrentUser
in my browser and getting a response perfectly fine (as in navigating to that page as a tab). However when I go to the chrome dev tools network pannel and download the HAR output and then import that into postman I get a 403 error?
I am not to sure what to do here as it is the exact same as far as i can tell?

I've checked for Auth
I've reset Postman cache
I've cleared cookies and all local data and made the same request again and reimported
Headers should be same due to import
Also does not work by using the copy as curl from network tab (same output as postman)
I disabled CORS on chrome (--disable-web-securit) and can use copy fetch to use it in another domain
All headers are the same as in chrome (including user agent)


It could be the origin of your request. There might be some difference how the endpoint manages requests coming from different origins. The domain in the borwser might be allowed to access the endpoint but an API platform is forbidden to do so.
Read the logs on the backend fi you can.

What is the user-agent header for the postman request?

Probably CSRF protection
